# How to change the values in a column using for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to change the values of column based on an if-else conditions and am using FOR loop to do that. The data is shown below:

```
m1 m2 m3 a1 a2
0.5 0.7 0.2 10 20
0.1 0 0.2 30 40
```

I want to apply the following condition

```
ifelse(column > 0.5,1,0)
```

I tried using this code, but its not working:

```
for (k in 1:3){
  data$m[k] <- ifelse(data$m[k] > 0.5,1,0)
  }
```

I also tried using double square brackets [[ ]], but that's also not working. I used the same logic for a list which worked fine, but in this case the column names are string and am not sure how to change the code accordingly.

Comment: Try `data[] <- (data > .5) + 0`. Don't think loops. First, check what is already vectorised.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Wont that change all the columns, i want the condition to be applied on only the mi1-m3 columns.

Comment: Then, just `data[1:3] <- (data[1:3] > .5) + 0` OR `data[paste0("m", 1:3)] <- (data[paste0("m", 1:3)] > .5) + 0` if you don't want to use column locations *\waits for a new developments in the question*

Comment: You can also do ```data[paste0("m", 1:3)] <- sapply(data[paste0("m", 1:3)], `>`, .5) + 0``` in order to avoid matrix conversions. Also, see the `data.table` package if your data set is huge

Comment: @DavidArenburg: It works, thanks. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See bellow code, i think you will expecting this...

```
m<-data.frame(
  m1=c(0.5,0.1),
  m2=c(0.7,0),
  m3=c(0.2,0.2),
  a1=c(10,30),
  a2=c(20,40)
)

for(i in 1:3){
  m[,i]<-ifelse(m[,i]>0.5,1,0)
}
```

result is:

```
m1 m2 m3 a1 a2
0  1  0 10 20
0  0  0 30 40
```